# Why is hyperhomology well defined at all?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathscr{A}}$I am following Weibel's homological algebra. To define hyperderived functors and hyperhomology we require uniqueness of lifts up to homotopy. This is not so hard in the case of derived functors and projective resolutions; it's troubling me for the case of hyperderived functors and Cartan-Eilenberg resolutions. I use superscript $h,v$ to denote horizontal, vertical differentials and to denote horizontal, vertical cycles and boundaries.

Specifically, the problem is this: say $f:A\to B$ is a maps of complexes in an Abelian category $\A$ which has enough projectives. Say $\epsilon,P$ and $\eta,Q$ are Cartan-Eilenberg resolutions of $A,B$. By an extension of the Horseshoe lemma - following Weibel's proof that derived functors are $\delta$-functors - it can be argued lifts $F:P\to Q$ of $f$ exist. The task is this:

> Say both $F,G:P\to Q$ (maps of double complexes) lift $f$. Show that there is a homotopy of double complexes $F\simeq G$, meaning the existence of arrows $s^h_{p,q}:P_{p,q}\to Q_{p+1,q},s^v_{p,q}:P_{p,q}\to Q_{p,q+1}$ for all $p,q$ such that:
>
> $(1)$: $G-F=d^hs^h+s^hd^h+d^vs^v+s^vd^v$ with suitable indices
>
> $(2)$: $d^hs^v+s^vd^h=0=d^vs^h+s^hd^v$ with suitable indices

And yes, *I know* this was asked before. But the answer was unsatisfactory, as the omissions it makes are too serious and I cannot fill in the blanks.

So put $H=G-F$; this lifts the zero map $A\to B$ and we'd like to find a nullhomotopy. Trying to mimic the proof of the usual comparison theorem, we should proceed by induction. But I cannot even handle the base case.

So sure, $H:P_{p,0}\to Q_{p,0}$ is killed by $\eta:Q_{p,0}\to B_p$ and it factors through the kernel, which is the image of $d^v:Q_{p,1}\to Q_{p,0}$ and for surjectivity reasons we can further lift, via the projectivity property, to some map $t^v:P_{p,0}\to Q_{p,1}$. This isn't the thing we want since it won't satisfy $d^ht^v+t^vd^h=0$; there is no reason. So perhaps I need to modify $t^v$ in a suitable way; unclear. The vertical differentials can be constructed easily but don't satisfy everything I need them to satisfy.

How do we make the horizontal maps? I can't see that one either. The only map I have been able to construct doesn't seem to be a very good one. For projectivity reasons there are splittings $P_{p,q}\twoheadrightarrow Z^h_{p,q}(P)\twoheadrightarrow B^h_{p,q}(P)$, coming from the exact sequences $0\to Z\to P\to B\to 0$ and $0\to B\to Z\to H\to 0$; because $H:B^h_{p,q}(P)\to Q_{p,q}$ factors through $B^h_{p,q}(Q)$ and then lifts, for projectivity reasons, against $Q_{p+1,q}\twoheadrightarrow B^h_{p,q}(Q)$ so we can get a map $B^h_{p,q}(P)\to Q_{p+1,q}$ and compose to get a map $s:P_{p,q}\to Q_{p+1,q}$. This doesn't have any properties that are clearly useful. All I can say is that $d^hsd^h=Hd^h$.

What's worse is that I can't seem to find this written down and worked out anywhere else. Does anyone know the details of this construction or have a reference for it?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks! I had not, but they have everything I need.